# Reconnection using retrywhen rxjava2 in android

Tags: rx-java2

I have the following RxJava disposable where I listen to real-time updates from the server

```
someNetworkBaseFlowable
    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe({
        // handle success
    }, {
        // handle failure
    })
```

When network fails, this subscription fails and I loose the connectivity to the server even when the network is back.

I've been trying to us `retryWhen` to resubscribe to the server as follow

```
someNetworkBaseFlowable
    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .retryWhen { error ->
        error.flatMap {
            Flowable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
    }
    .subscribe({
        // handle succes
    }, {
        // handle failure
    })
```

I though this would try to ping or reconnect to the server and resubscribe every 5 seconds, however this is not the case!

I've been struggling for a while, and any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Initially, it looks OK. Can you let us know how are you validating that it's not retrying? Is your code getting to the `flatMap` inside `retryWhen`?

Answer (score 0):

You may slightly modify your code as follows:

```
  someNetworkBaseFlowable
      .observeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
      .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .retryWhen { errorFlowable : Flowable<Throwable> ->

          errorFlowable
          .ofType(YourExceptionType::class.java) // for Kotlin
          // .ofType(YourExceptionType.class) // for Java

          .switchMap{ // to avoid duplicates
              Flowable.timer(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          }
      }
      .subscribe(
      {
          // handle succes
      }, 
      {
          // handle failure
      })
```

Does it retries now if YourExceptionType is caught?